# PDAL merging multiple LAZ files from folder in Python

Tags: python, lidar, pdal

I am attempting to merge multiple laz files stored in a specific directory. I have seen in the PDAL documentation that *PDAL doesn’t handle matching multiple file inputs except for glob handling for merge operations*, which lead me to find this pipeline:

```
json = """ 
    { 
        "pipeline": [
            'path/to/data/\*.laz,
            'mergedtestout.las'
        ]
    } """   

import pdal
pipeline = pdal.Pipeline(json)
count = pipeline.execute()
```

I also normally work with the other Python notation for PDAL, e.g.:

```
pipeline = (
   pdal.Readers.las(filename="whatever.las")
   | pdal.Filters.merge()
   | pdal.Witers.las(filename="output.las")

pipeline.execute()
```

But apparently this notation is not working now when I glob the files I am interested with. Basically this code is not working:

```
import glob
files = glob.glob(path + '\.*laz')
   pipeline = (
        pdal.Reader.las(filesname=files)
        | pdal.Filter.merge()
        | pdal.Writer.las(output_file)
    )

    print("Executing pipeline to merge files inside directory")
    pipeline.execute()
```

However I do not get any result out of that. The first code yields this error `raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 4 column 13 (char 43)` and the second code this one `RuntimeError: JSON pipeline: 'filename' must be specified as a string.`.

Has anybody encountered and solved a similar issue previously?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I solved it like this:

```
    lazfiles =  lazpath + '\*.laz'
outfile = output_file

print("PDAL pipeline")

pipeline = (
    pdal.Reader.las(filename=lazfiles)
    | pdal.Filter.merge()
    | pdal.Writer.las(outfile)
)

print("Executing pipeline to merge files inside directory")
pipeline.execute()
```